# VBA - SaveAs - runtime error if network not accessable

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to save an excel file into a network drive with the code bellow.
The problem is that if the network is not accessable, it gives a runtime error.

CAn you please help how to modify the code 
- to save file on given network drive if network accessable
- if not, save into local machine (create a copy in doucuments folder)

Thanks

```
Dim datum_ As String
Dim path_ As String
datum_ = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm")
path_ = "\\networkfolder"

'Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=path_ & datum_ & ".xlsm"
'Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
'.... code
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
On Error Resume Next
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=path_ & datum_ & ".xlsm"
If Err.Number <> 0 Then ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=myLocalPath_ & datum_ & ".xlsm"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
On Error Goto 0
' .... code
```

Comment: An "End if" should be added , but works!

Thanks for both!

Answer (score 1):

You could use error handling, so if there is an error change the path to something local.

```
Dim datum_ As String
Dim path_ As String
datum_ = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm")
path_ = "\\networkfolder"

On Error GoTo localPath
'Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=path_ & datum_ & ".xlsm"
'Application.DisplayAlerts = True

'rest of code here
Exit Sub

localPath:
path_ = "insert local path here"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=path_ & datum_ & ".xlsm"
```

Comment: The `ErrHandler` is called in all cases. Why not check `If Err.Number<>0 Then ...`

Comment: Didn't think of that, can just put a different error handler after the save line to deal with all other errors.

Comment: I mean you're saving locally even if no error occurs?

Comment: Edited to avoid this situation. Im sure there are better solutions, but this is one.